# To what extent is the Paris agreement legally binding?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, climate-change, paris-agreement

In the [UNFCCC site](https://unfccc.int/process-and-meetings/the-paris-agreement/the-paris-agreement) the Paris agreement is defined as *a **legally binding** international treaty on climate change*. Its goal is to limit global warming below +2°C *through nationally determined contirbutions* (NDC) to global carbon emissions, but the NDC's [are not themselves legally binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationally_Determined_Contributions).

What part of the treaty is legally binding and enforceable?

It would be ironic if the parties were obliged to present their commitments, but not to respect them...

Comment: I don't see why the link prvoided should answer my question, as there i's no reference to any binding mechanism. As far as I understand is is somehow binding (why is it presented as binding on the unfccc site then?) and I guess is about  *presenting* the contribution. The linked question asks "what is the point" it is a very different question and in fact the answer doesn't address the point